# How to detect automorphism of union of graphs?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

On page 1 of [Lecture 2, Algebra and Computation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidyO33-_DMAhUFr48KHYtYANQQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmi.ac.in%2F~ramprasad%2Flecturenotes%2Falgcomp%2Flecture2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGNgmivjTbCUL7DOCt4IgW-GA09UQ&sig2=u3G28v7mrfuyQfIRLypLpQ)  , (Course Instructor: V. Arvind),  there is a theorem-

> Theorem 2. With Graph − Iso (graph isomorphism) as an oracle, there is a 
>   polynomial time algorithm for Graph − Aut (automorphism) and vice-versa.

on page 2, the proof is given-

> Proof. First we shall show that we can solve Graph−Iso with Graph−Aut
>   as an oracle. We are given two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ and we need to create
>   a graph G using the two such that the generating set of the
>   automorphism should tell us if they are isomorphic or not.
>   Let $G = G_1 \cup G_2$. Suppose additionally we knew that $G_1$ and
>   $G_2$ are connected, then a single oracle query would be sufficient.
>   If any of the generators of $Aut(G)$ interchanged a vertex in $G_1$
>   with one in $G_2$, then connnectivity should force $G_1 \simeq G_2$.
>   But what if they are not connected? We then have this very neat trick,
>   $G_1 \simeq G_2  \Leftrightarrow \bar G_1\simeq \bar G_2$ , and either
>   $G_1$ or $\bar G_1$ has to be connected and hence one can check for
>   connectivity and then ask the appropriate query.

$\bar G_1$ is the complement graph of $G_1$, I assume.

It is said that-

> Suppose additionally we knew that $G_1$ and
>   $G_2$ are connected, then a single oracle query would be sufficient.

But when we  test graph isomorphism, $G_1 , G_2$ are two different disconnected graph. Is it why it went on like-

> But what if they are not connected? We then have this very neat trick,
>   $G_1 \simeq G_2  \Leftrightarrow \bar G_1\simeq \bar G_2$, and either
>   $G_1$ or $\bar G_1$ has to be connected and hence one can check for
>   connectivity and then ask the appropriate query.

So, are we checking whether there is an automorphism of  $G' = \bar G_1 \cup \bar G_2$ that swaps a vertex of $\bar G_1$ with  a vertex of $\bar G_2$?

How can we tell that this kind of swapping is an automorphism?

Comment: Example:   $r$ is a permutation that swaps only 2 vertices of $ G_1$ . Let, $G_1^{r} = G_2$.  Let, $G= G_1 \cup  G_2$. Clearly, $G$ is a disconnected  graph, so we try  $G' = \bar G_1 \cup  \bar G_2$ instead of $G$. But how we detect an automorphism of $G'$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are checking whether there is an automorphism of $G^{\prime} = \bar{G}_{1} \cup \bar{G}_{2}$ that swaps a vertex of $\bar{G}_{1}$ with a vertex of $\bar{G}_{2}$. You are using Graph-Aut as an oracle, so what you will do is use Graph-Aut to find the automorphism group of $G^{\prime}$ (returned as a set of generators), then just look at whether any of these generators swap vertices of $G_{1}$ with those of $G_{2}$.  You don't need to do anything to tell if this swapping is an automorphism, it is automatically an automorphism because it's returned by Graph-Aut.

Comment: probably I am making a mistake here,  does $G_1 \cup G_2$  has any edge between  $G_1 , G_2$  ? similarly, does  $\bar G_1 \cup \bar G_2$  has any has any edge between   $\bar G_1  ,  \bar G_2$   ?